# custom balancers in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Have you written custom balancers for sharding to balance chunks not using the balancer in MongoDB and would you please explain your use case that why you had to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's been a few cases I've managed where a custom balancing script has been temporarily useful, for example, where there's a regional requirement for data on certain shards or if certain collections shouldn't be balanced.  There's no real advantage in terms of speed (that's limited by data distribution in disk and memory, mostly), in fact one reason to do custom balancing is to make it go slower.

It's finicky to get right though - and generally not worth it long-term in my experience.  There's a balancer window you can use to do time-based balancing and, in the future, chunk tagging and the ability to mark collections as "don't balance" will make custom scripts unnecessary for most other tasks.

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2545
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4621

Answer (score 0):

Two answers for the price of one:

1. **Goal:  Slower balancing** - A custom balancer could be written to go more slowly, adding time delays between each balance round.  This could be used to lower the IOPS / disk throughput in cases where you're sharing throughput with other (presumably more important) applications.  I might suggest looking into using the unix 'nice' on your daemons, or setting up balancing to use a schedule (see Mongo docs).

Note: With MongoDB version 2.4, the default changed for **secondaryThrottle** to verify that data is written to secondaries before going forward with the chunk migration.  This can vastly slow down chunk migration if you just disable your secondaries.  To fix this, type:

```
use config
db.settings.update({"_id":"balancer"},{$set:{"_secondaryThrottle":false}})
```

1. **Goal:  Faster balancing** - We all know the balancer can take forever to balance wildly disparate chunk counts, on the order of days.  I have NOT written this kind of balancer, but I can easily see how it could be one.  There is a presumption that only one chunk can move at one time.  If we presume that we have large numbers of shards (say, 48 of them), and each has its own disk/device, this migration concept could DEFINITELY be sped up by pairing off shards/chunks to be migrated and having it all go in parallel.

What we don't know is, *What effects this has on the config server*.  Are there presumptions in the way the config server works that would make it break if we had 2+ simultaneous moves?  Sounds like it's time to look a the config server code.

Or, one of us could ask 10Gen whether, if you/I/we wrote such an animal, if it would be useful or just result in pain and death, or, even worse, being forced to live in Mississippi.